# Parsing HTML with Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am new to using Python Regex. I am trying to pull out some data from HTML and not sure what the correct syntax is to do this correctly

I've got the following data and I want to pull the data Birthdate = 'July 4, 1969', Hometown = 'Colts Neck, N.J.', College = 'Penn State, 1991', Post-graduate = 'Virginia, 1996'

```
data = <b>Birthdate:</b> July 4, 1969<br/><b>Hometown:</b> Colts Neck, N.J.<br/><b>College:</b> Penn State, 1991<br/><b>Post-graduate:</b> Virginia, 1996</td></tr></table>
Birthdate = re.findall(r'<b>Birthdate:</b>(.*)<br/>', data)
Hometown = re.findall(r'<b>Hometown:></b>(.*)<br/>', data)
College = re.findall(r'<b>College:</b>(.*)<br/>, data)
Post-graduate = re.findall(r,<b>Post-graduate:</b>(.*)<td/>, data)
```

Admittedly, I am not using re.findall or the wildcard `(.*)` correctly here because I get a string returned that starts at the value that I want and goes to the end of data to the last 
 tag. I would like to use a function that pulls the data between the pattern that I defining
`(.*)` in this example.

Comment: Come on, there are plenty of HTML parsers out there. Don't use regexes for that.

Comment: Pick an html parser. Regex is doomed by non-standard HTML that browsers have forced to work. See also "tidy", as a filter, if a parser that you choose does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `regex` then you may consider this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''data = <b>Birthdate:</b> July 4, 1969<br/><b>Hometown:</b> Colts Neck, N.J.<br/><b>College:</b> Penn State, 1991<br/><b>Post-graduate:</b> Virginia, 1996</td></tr></table>'''
>>> dict(re.findall(r'<b>([^:]*):</b> *([^<]*)', s))
{'Hometown': 'Colts Neck, N.J.', 'Birthdate': 'July 4, 1969', 'College': 'Penn State, 1991', 'Post-graduate': 'Virginia, 1996'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This re.findall and conversion to a dictionary worked perfectly for what I needed to do. What are the better libraries to use do to this type of parsing in the future?

Comment: In future use BeautifulSoup parser.